# how is the correct way to use copy_from_user?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to copy a value from user space to kernel space with the function:

```
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t  *off) 
{

    unsigned long copy=0;
    int desp=0; 

    copy = copy_from_user(&desp, &len, 4);  

    printk(KERN_ALERT "copy: %lx\n", copy);      
    printk(KERN_ALERT "desp: %d\n", desp);
}
```

where "len" is the variable that exists in the user space, and I want to copy it to "desp" in the kernel space

the function call I make from the user space is (write is device_write according to file_operations struct):

```
 write (fd,buffer,8, &off);
```

when I print the value that should be stored in "desp" is always 0 (should be 8).
What is the problem in my code? I've been seeing several examples and I implemented many variations but none works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `write` function prototype in the manual is:

`ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);`

So you only need to pass 3 values to `write`, namely: the file descriptor `fd`, `buffer` where your data lies, and `count` of bytes you want to write.

This regarding the user space. Now let's move to the kernel space write function, i.e. your `device_write`.

The argument `buf` to this function is the one which contains data which you want to write from user space, `count` is the length of data sent to be written by the kernel. So you are supposed to copy data from `buf` pointer and not `len`.

So, the correct way would be:

```
char *desp;  //allocate memory for this in kernel using malloc
copy_from_user (desp, buff, len);
```

This should do.

Comment: the problem was that the system call only has 3 parameters, and I wanted to use the 4, that are in the method of the file operations structure (device_read/write).

Thus, when placed into the kernel space, the compiler does not give any warning of the number of parameters which have methods (which is different)

I tried doing a system llamdas 5 parameters! and the compilation and execution are not warned of any problem ...

Thanks for your answers!!!

Answer (score 4):

`len` does *not* exist in user-space.  It is passed by value, so `len` is accessible as a normal variable in kernel-space.  `desp = (int)len` is all you need.  Note, however, that size_t is not the same as int, and on 64-bit platforms size_t is 8 bytes.

`copy_from_user()` is for the buffer you're trying to write (called `buffer` in your user-space code, and `buff` in your kernel-space argument list).  What's passed is a pointer to a memory address which only exists in user-space, so `copy_from_user()` copies that buffer to a kernel-space buffer.

Comment: sure, but my idea is to pass the 4th parameter, offset (loff_t *) and does not reach the kernel space when I make calls from user space.
So I see these variables as user space.

On the other hand, if I can access directly "buff" from kernel space ...

Comment: How can you make that call from user space?  `write()` is a defined system call interface that takes 3 parameters.  The C library and the kernel VFS layer translate that call eventually into your `device_write()` handler.  You can't just add a 4th argument, and the compiler won't let you.  Are you looking for `pwrite` instead?  Anyway, what does this have to do with your question, which I answered?  If you mean to ask something different, fix your question

Comment: 'll read about pwrite / read to try to implement that system call, many thanks!

Comment: Peter, pread/pwrite are not implemented in the struct file operations, in my kernel 3.6 (arm)

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h?v=3.6;a=arm

i have to use ioctl...

Comment: pread/pwrite are user-space functions.  The kernel-side functions already can take an offset argument!  That's the point!  The problem so far is that the user-space call you're using doesn't let you specify the offset.  So use a different user-space call (pwrite).

Comment: pwrite is a different function that is implemented in the file operations

system call:
ssize_t pwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset);

file operations: 
ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);

(different arguments :) )

the system call pwrite are not implemented in the file operations!

Comment: You are still confused about the difference between kernel-space file operations handlers, and user-space system calls.  When a user wants to write a to file, he calls the function write (or pwrite, or writev or pwritev).  From there, the C library turns that function call into a system call.  From here, you're in kernel space.  Then, the kernel goes through several translation steps, before that call finally arrives at the file operations handler.  Trust me!  Just try it!  Call pwrite from user-space and watch the call show up in your write() handler.

Comment: when I call pwrite, and make the modification in the file operations:

static struct file_operations fops = {
 .read    = device_read, 
 .pwrite   = device_write,
 .open    = device_open,
 .release = device_release
};

the compiler tells me that pwrite not defined in the structure.

how is the way to call the function device_write (ssize_t (* write) (struct file *, const char __ user *, size_t, loff_t *))
  from the application as "pwrite"? how is the file operations struct?

Comment: I made the pwrite system call, with the 4 parameters and it worked!
mapping the file_operations is with. write = device_write... :O

Obviously I do not understand how calls are made to the system and how are linking with the functions in the struct file_operations. Can you give me some link or reading material on this subject? thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, and does not say the way to instantiate the file operations structure,if I have, for example, 4 types of writing in the application. How and why are all the same write method of the structure.And what happens to the write system call parameters (which are 3 parameters) if the method in the file operations requested four parameters?
that is not explained or not understood....

Comment: Hi @eduardosufan  as Peter suggested did you called  "pwrite from user-space " if so can you please let me know how did you called??