# Pointers given from user space to kernel space are null

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Sorry if this question has been asked before as it seems kind of basic, but I can't find it anywhere on this site.
I'm doing OS programming with linux (debian) and I'm trying to give a pointer from my user space to my kernel space function.

Namely in the userspace I do

```
    ...
    long res;
    int x = -1;
    int *p1 = &x;  // also tried doing a malloc, didn't change anything
    res = kernel_function(p1);
    ...
```

and in the kernel space file kernel_function.c I do

```
asmlinkage long kernel_function( int __user *p){
    printk("%p \n", (void*) p);
    return 0;
}
```

I also did the usual other steps, like adding the prototype of the function to syscalls.h, adding the file name to syscall_32.tbl and such. But when I run my user space function the only thing that gets printed to the kernel log is (NULL). So the function does get called, but the pointer is lost, any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't look at any other Linux kernel functions?

You cannot just pass a pointer. That would be horribly unsafe.

You are required to use copy_from_user to get data into kernel space.

There seem to be some answers already on SO like this one: [how is the correct way to use copy_from_user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490479/how-is-the-correct-way-to-use-copy-from-user)

Comment: printk, apart from missing log level, was perfectly fine. The note about using copy_from_user is also fine and worthwile, although somewhat incomplete - not only direct derefence can be a security and reliability problem, it may straight up not work on architectures with separate address spaces. However, OP screwed up something else. Chances are they are either calling the syscall wrong in their wrapper. or incorrectly specified the syscall. Both things can be remedied by looking at real-world code doing the work.