# Are system calls thread-safe?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, chardev

I have wrote a kernel module, It is a Character device driver something like [this Link](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html).The driver has an internal structure like:

```
struct {
    str[500];
}channelData;

static channelData chData[4];
```

So I have a multi-threaded application which uses this driver, I currently use this driver in following way:

```
typedef struct
{
        int channelId;
        int len;
        char arg[100];
} driverArgs;

class DevDrv{
    static void STR_READ(int channelId, char *data);
    static void STR_SEND(int channelId, char *data,int len);
};

void DevDrv::STR_READ(int channelId, char *data)
{
    driverArgs arg= {-1,0, {0}};
    arg.channelId = channelId;
    ioctl(mfilehandler,IOCTL_STR_READ,&arg);
    memcpy(data,arg.arg,arg.len)

}
void DevDrv::STR_SEND(int channelId, char *data,int len)
{
    driverArgs arg= {-1,0, {0}};
    arg.channelId = channelId;
    arg.len=len;
    memcpy(arg.arg,data,len);
    ioctl(mfilehandler,IOCTL_STR_SEND,&arg);
}
```

So, The question is if 4 threads in my application call these functions to read or write into their own ChannelId like this to read from or write into driver:

```
thread1:
   DevDrv::STR_READ(0,&localdst);
thread2:
   DevDrv::STR_READ(1,&localdst);
thread3:
   DevDrv::STR_READ(2,&localdst);
thread4:
   DevDrv::STR_READ(3,&localdst);
```

is there data-racing or something like that happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17490479/1216776

Answer (score 1):

Your `channelData` structure is not guaranteed to be cache-aligned, so unless you explicitly synchronize `chData`, you're still subject to data races.

Here's a sketch of a race:

1. System call wants to read into channel 2 on CPU 0.
2. CPU 0 fetches all the cache lines containing channel 2, which means:

   - All the bytes in channel 2
   - A few bytes from the end of channel 1
   - A few bytes from the beginning of channel 3
3. The read goes as usual.
4. CPU 1 writes 500 bytes to channel 1.
5. System call wants to read 500 bytes into channel 1 on CPU 0.
6. CPU 0 fetches all the bytes from channel 1 which weren't previously fetched.

   - The few bytes from the end of channel 1 are not re-fetched

In this scenario, those few bytes are stale on CPU 0, because they were overwritten by CPU 1, and CPU 0 wasn't aware.

It wasn't aware, because there wasn't a [memory barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) telling it its cache might be stale.

Now, in many instances, a system call triggers a memory barrier, BUT it is not guaranteed.

Your userspace program is fine, and a character device is the canonical way to communicate with a kernel module, but your kernel module has to synchronize properly. Even the example in your link seems to be trying to be very introductory and does things like `Device_Open++` without using atomics.